# Is there a correlation between sukha and passadha?

Tags: jhana, meditation-effects

Is there a correlation between sukha (the 4th component of the jhanangas) and passadha (the 5th component of the sambojjhanga)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Piti arises and you stay equanimously watching the arising and passing knowing its impermanence (with no attachment or craving to this feeling) then Piti will fade away and Passadhi will arise. When Passadhi initially arises you may think your meditation is regressing as you loose Piti and also board after a few hours of Passadhi.

Piti is a stage which is conducive to tame Sankara resulting from craving.

Passadhi is a stage which is conducive to tame Sankara from Ignorance or Sanna.

Comment: Do you really mean Sanna? Not Dosa?

Answer (score 0):

Sukha isn't one of the 7 Bojjhangas, although Piti (rapture) is the fourth of them so I think that's what you meant. Yes, there is a connection. When Piti is developed correctly it will lead to Passadha (which simply means tranquility or peace.) For example, in the section on the Bojjhangas in the Anapanasati Sutta it says:

> "[4] In one whose persistence is aroused, a rapture not-of-the-flesh
>   arises. When a rapture not-of-the-flesh arises in one whose
>   persistence is aroused, then rapture as a factor for awakening becomes
>   aroused. He develops it, and for him it goes to the culmination of its
>   development.
>
> "[5] For one enraptured at heart, the body grows calm and the mind
>   grows calm. When the body & mind of a monk enraptured at heart grow
>   calm, then serenity as a factor for awakening becomes aroused. He
>   develops it, and for him it goes to the culmination of its
>   development.
>   http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.118.than.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not just a strong correlation, it's the direct cause.
http://lucid24.org/sn/sn46/sn46-003/toc-addon/index.html

It's not just that sutta, SN 46.3.

Doing a search for passaddha-kāyo sukhaṃ returns (60 hits).
At least 60 sutta references to that same 7sb awakening factor sequence.
passaddha-kāyo sukhaṃ: (with) pacified-body, [physical] pleasure (results)

Answer (score -1):

There is no correlation between sukha (the 4th component of the jhanangas) and passadha (the 5th component of the sambojjhanga) because there is no correlation between passadha and jhana.

The rapture of sambojjhanga is not the rapture of jhana. This is quite obvious because the rapture of sambojjhanga arises before the concentration of sambojjhanga, as follows:

> For one whose mind is uplifted by rapture the body becomes tranquil and the mind becomes tranquil.... For one whose body is tranquil and who is happy the mind becomes concentrated.
>
> SN 46.3

The rapture of sambojjhanga is merely the rapture that occurs when the 1st and particularly the 2nd  sambojjhanga are being practised successfully.

This type of rapture is similar to the rapture below that occurs due to faith in the teachings about ending suffering, which is not jhana:

> "Tranquillity, monks, also has a supporting condition, I say, it does
> not lack a supporting condition. And what is the supporting condition
> for tranquillity? 'Rapture' should be the reply.
>
> "Rapture, monks, also has a supporting condition, I say, it does not
> lack a supporting condition. And what is the supporting condition for
> rapture? 'Joy' should be the reply.
>
> "Joy, monks, also has a supporting condition, I say, it does not lack
> a supporting condition. And what is the supporting condition for joy?
> 'Faith' should be the reply.
>
> "Faith, monks, also has a supporting condition, I say, it does not
> lack a supporting condition. And what is the supporting condition for
> faith? 'Suffering' should be the reply.
>
> SN 12.23

Comment: Do your homework and look at what passaddhi (pacification/relaxation) is doing in SN 36.11, DN 2, among dozens of other suttas. It's all over the place and completely intertwined with the 4 jhanas. By your half baked logic, sati-sambojjhanga, upekkha-sambojjhanga, are also "therefore not part of 4 jhanas because they are different awakening factors that aren't equivalent to samadhi-sambojjhanga." Then why is sati and upekkha explicitly included in 3rd and 4th jhana?

Comment: When a certain word is used in different contexts, does not mean it has the same meaning. For example, in SN 36.11, passaddhā of speech, vitakka and vicara occurs before passaddhā of rapture. Therefore, that rapture in sambojjhanga could occur before passaddhā in sambojjhanga is illogical.